# Is it possible to remove a duplicate value from a datatable in c#?

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicates

I have a datatable with a column `MobileNo`.... My datatable has `150` rows and each row has `MobileNo`... Now how to check every `MobileNo` is unique by parsing all the datarows of the datatable in c#?

**EDIT:**

"This datatable is being created by reading a CSV file"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Linq and Group By the MobileNo then you will need to traverse the collection and see which MobileNo's have multiple records and then do whatever you wish to remove what you deem is duplicated.

**Edit:** From [Linq 101 Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1).

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(bool distinct, string[] ColumnNames)
```

the third overload on that is what your looking for I believe, let me know how you get on.

- Specify which columns are to be deduped in the string[]
- And a true false for distinct records

So you can either just select a subset of data out or dedupe by setting distinct to true.

You will need to do some jiggery  pokery to get your dataset how you want it, but I think thats what your after.